# Radon measure and a non-L1 function

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

This is a part of the exercise 7.17 in Folland's Real Analysis:

Suppose $\mu$ is a positive Radon measure on a locally compact Hausdorff space $X $ with $\mu (X)=\infty. $ Show that there exists $f\in C_0 (X) $ such that $\int_X f d\mu=\infty. $

I guess if we can choose a sequence of disjoint open sets having compact subsets such that the sum of measure of cpt subsets is $\infty $, then done. But the space is not normal in general.. I'm totally confused with it.

Comment: Does Folland cover the Urysohn lemma? In a locally compact Hausdorff space, given a compact set $K$ and an open set $U$ containing $K$, there exists a continuous function $f$ such that $0 \le f \le 1$, $f = 1$ on $K$, and $f = 0$ outside $U$.

Try to work with a sequence $\{K_j\}$ of compact sets whose measures tend toward $\infty$ and construct appropriate $f_j$. Your $f$ can be defined using a series.

Comment: I thought similarly.. can I separate a  closed set and a compact set in a LCH space? I guess the space should be normal.

Comment: Hmm I guess the statement in Folland misses something out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\mu$ is Radon, it is inner regular on open sets, in particular on $X$.

Thus, there is a sequence of compact sets $K_n$ with $\mu(K_n) > 4^n$.

By the Urysohn-Lemma, there is a function $f_n \in C_c(X)$ with $0 \leq f_n \leq 1$ and with $f_n \equiv 1 $ on $K_n$.

Now the $M$-test shows that

$$
f := \sum_n 2^{-n} f_n
$$
converges uniformly and hence to a function in $C_0$ (since $C_0$ is closed with respect to uniform convergence).

But the monoton convergence theorem shows

$$
\int f \, d\mu = \sum_n 2^{-n} \int f_n \, d\mu \geq \sum_n 2^{-n} \mu(K_n) = \sum_n 2^n = \infty.
$$